# How to change cite keys with biber / biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, biber, bibtool

If I understand correctly, it's possible to change / reformat cite keys according to a predefined scheme with BibTex using bibtool, eg:

`bibtool -k foo.bib`

... so that the cite keys in a bib file will be transformed from whatever state they were previously in to follow a consistent scheme of `author:title`, resulting is some like:

`@Book{ dickens:olivertwist,`

When working with biber and biblatex, is it possible to do the same type of thing and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature of `bibtool` works independently of how you produce your bibliography from the `.bib` file. It will work no matter if you want to use your `.bib` file with BibTeX or `biblatex`.

In general all features of `bibtool` that do not rely on an `.aux` file should in principle work independently of BibTeX for `biblatex` as well, since they only rewrite the `.bib` file with information contained in the `.bib` file. There are, however, small differences between the 'best input' between standard `biblatex` and 'standard' BibTeX (styles can always define new fields and types), so sometimes care might be needed (for example BibTeX usually uses `year`, where `biblatex` prefers `date`).

Comment: Thanks, fast answer. I realise this is slightly off topic, but is bibtool installable via tlmgr? I'm having trouble locating it.

Comment: @paulswanson I don't think it is. If you are using Linux it may be available via your distribution (I managed to install it via `apt` on Ubuntu), but I don't think I have seen compiled binaries for Windows. Not sure about macOS. Other software such as JabRef should also be able to regenerate entry keys, so if `bibtool` isn't easily available on your platform, check out JabRef (https://docs.jabref.org/setup/bibtexkeypatterns).

Comment: Linux, so will be easy enough to acquire. Thanks again.